# jQuery element selection in Firefox addon isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to attach an event handler to button element using jQuery in firefox extension's popup page.

HTML - `<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">`

jQuery selector - `$('#submitButton').click(function() {...});`

The problem is that the click event isn't intercepted. Also, I've tried native js id selector but to no avail.

`var item=document.getElementById('submitButton');`

`item` evaluates to `null`.

I've run out of options to try. Does anyone have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Debugger doesn't attach to the process and so execution doesn't pause at breakpoints.

I had to write `console.log()`s to output the state of the objects and take it from there.

`console.log()` logs to Firefox console.